# UITextView scrolling is not working

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

Scrolling is not working in UITextView for the messageLabel in the following code 
sizeDictionary is a dictionary which contains the sizes of all the labels/textviews calculated according to the text.i have set the scrollEnabled as well as the userInteractionEnabled property to true.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.91 alpha:1];
    self.messageLabel = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    if(self.feed.message){
        self.messageLabel.text = self.feed.message;
    }else if (self.feed.story){
        self.messageLabel.text = self.feed.story;
    }
    self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Droid Sans" size:15];
    self.messageLabel.editable = NO;
    self.messageLabel.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    self.messageLabel.scrollEnabled = true;
    self.messageLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true;

    self.messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.078 green:0.094 blue:0.137 alpha:1.00];
self.cardView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1];
[self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:false];
self.cardView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5 + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width - 10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"imageHeight"] floatValue]+ [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] + [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue] + 20);
self.cardView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.cardView];
self.nameLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 15+ self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 51);

self.dateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 45+ self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, 25);
self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue]  + 20 + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width - 20, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue]);
self.messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.messageLabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.dateLabel];
[self.view addSubview:self.nameLabel];
if (self.image) {
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue] + [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue] + 25 + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height , self.view.bounds.size.width - 20, [self.sizeDictionary[@"imageHeight"] floatValue]);
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    }
}
```

[image]

edit: added

```
self.messageLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1 ;
self.messageLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

[image]

Comment: there is more text beyond of 8 and are hidden?

Comment: yes there are 10 points in total. This screen is just an example the text is coming from a json. This view is displayed when didSelectAtIndexPath method is called in the previous table vie. the text is actually transferred in the didSelect method

Comment: can you add this peace of code `self.messageLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1 ;` `self.messageLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;` ? and check if your messageLabel frame is full visible?

Comment: which one exactly? should i add the whole viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad? or the table view?

Comment: check again I hit "enter" before end my comment sorry

Comment: i have added the screenshot of the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well is easy then your problem is with the frame of `messageLabel` you need to adjust your `messageLabel` frame and will became scrolleable because your `messageLabel.frame.heigth` will be smaller than your `messageLabel` content size

adjust this line

```
self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, [self.sizeDictionary[@"nameHeight"] floatValue]  + 20 + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width - 20, [self.sizeDictionary[@"messageHeight"] floatValue]);
```

your `self.messageLabel.frame` can´t be as the size your need by the objects you have there, if this happens then your `UITextView` never will scroll because your frame.height will be equal to your contentSize

I hope this helps you